# Importar biblioteca no VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Como importar uma *lib* no Visual Studio 2010, estou realizando um projeto que preciso usar:

```
  using  System.Data.Entity 4.0
  using  System.Data.DataSetExtensions 4.0
```

Tenho o arquivo que contém a *lib*, mas como faço para colocá-lo no VS?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

A [referência canônica está aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/wkze6zky(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) na documentação da Microsoft.

Seria isto:

[image: SS]

- clique com o botão direito no nós `References`
- escolha `Add Reference`
- clique na *tab* `Browse`
- Navegue pelas opções apresentadas até achar o que deseja inserir no projeto.
- Ok.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fiz isso e continuo nao conseguindo usa-la.. está na pasta correta.. mas não consigo!

Comment: Esse 4.0 você colocou só para exemplificar ou está escrito? Dá algum erro? Posta tudo o que puder aí na sua pergunta. Experimentou instalar com Nuget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Entity.Repository/