# Como faço para compilar esse projeto em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, compilação

Estou tendo problemas para compilar com o comando CSC no *prompt* e está dando um erro de "namespace" que não estou conseguindo arrumar.
Não sei se estou fazendo certo.

[image: erro csc]

[Link do projeto](http://www.xtibia.com/forum/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=20741).

Comment: Link do projeto não é muito útil, pois como no meu caso o site que você está referenciando está bloqueado no firewall. Edite sua pergunta e acrescente o código nela para que todos possamos verificar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Tem que dizer o que deseja usar de biblioteca.

```
csc /r:Mono.dll /t:onde_estao_as_bibliotecas *.cs
```

Certamente aparecerão outros erros.

Tenho minhas dúvidas se conseguirá usar o Mono no `csc`. Até dá, mas dá trabalho.

Aconselho instalar o Visual Studio e fazer por ele, é bem mais fácil para quem não tem conhecimento.

Comment: Mas como posso fazer pelo visual studio 2015 pq já tentei.

Comment: Isso é outra pergunta. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40770/101. Se você não consegue fazer em uma ferramenta que tem a dica a interface, é muito mais difícil em outra que nem isso tem. É o que eu falei, surgirão vários problemas. Se você não for estudar o assunto a fundo não chegará a lugar algum.